# Change H3 text to input val with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have hopefully a very straight forward question. I have an H3 tag with some text in it. I need to have that text show up as the text value inputted in a text field, How can I make the H3 text the same as the text field with Jquery?

Here is the ID of the H3,   detectiveFill_1
here is the ID of the input   loc_else_text

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will update the `h3` element on input focus lost

```
$('#loc_else_text').change(function(){
    $('#detectiveFill_1').text(this.value);
});
```

This will update instantly on key pressed

```
$('#loc_else_text').keyup(function(){
    $('#detectiveFill_1').text(this.value);
})
```

Comment: I dont know why, but the H3 text is not being updated, the text stays the same.

Comment: @user2089255: that's weird. Here you have a sample for the second approach http://jsfiddle.net/u86Xx/

Comment: Yea weird, the code you have loos 100% right, ill figure out what i'm doing wrong. Thanks for the fiddle! Ill make it work.

Comment: Could it be because the input field itself is also inside an H3 tag?

Comment: Sweet, it was because the input was inside an H3, I got it working, thanks a bunch!